# a really basic implementation for hibernate calls plsql function

Tags: oracle, hibernate, configuration, plsql

i really need a basic hibernate implementation calls oracle plsql function.
it must include configurations, dao and test class.

is there any example for that?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to get started with the official documentation, the section [16.2.2. Using stored procedures for querying](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#sp_query) also covers functions? I doubt you'll find exactly what your asking for. And if you face a specific problem, ask a more specific question.

#### References

- Hibernate Core Reference Guide

  - [16.2.2. Using stored procedures for querying](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#sp_query)